# Protocol Extension in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview

I need to add some behavior to UICollectionViewDataSource.

If I were to create a Collection View extension, I would do:

```
extension UICollectionView
{
  func thisWorks() {}
}
```

But attempting to do it for the Data Source causes a "Protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource' cannot be extended" error.

```
extension UICollectionViewDataSource
{
  func thisDoesntWork() {}
}
```

Is there a way to add a new func to a protocol?

Comment: This is now possible in Swift 2. Checkout session 408 from WWDC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reported in [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-XID_229):

> Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, or enumeration type

So extending a protocol is **not** possible - they support inheritance, which means you can subclass a protocol.

However, I think that protocol extension wouldn't make much sense. If you extend `UICollectionViewDataSource`, it means that all classes adopting it would fail to compile because of the new requirements set by the extensions - including UIKit classes, such as `UICollectionViewController`, which itself implements `UICollectionViewDataSource`

In your case, I think that there are 2 solutions:

- create a new protocol inherited from `UICollectionViewDataSource`
- create a separated protocol, not linked to `UICollectionViewDataSource` (but most likely having a similar name)

I would choose option no. 2, because the former makes the code less readable, by hiding the `UICollectionViewDataSource` name in your class declaration.

Comment: Right, I didn't realize adding a method would break other classes adopting it, but it totally makes sense. I will probably go with the first solution, though. Second one wouldn't let me use classes which extend this new protocol as UICollectionViewDataSources.

Comment: Ok - by the way I think that you can combine both options: implement `UICollectionViewDataSource` in your class, *and* inherit from it in your new protocol. Little redundancy, but I think code is more explicit

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. And you don't need to - anything expecting to work with a `UICollectionViewDataSource` is only expecting particular methods to be there. Just declare your own custom protocol, conform to that, and then use it in your classes where appropriate:

```
extension MyCustomCollectionViewDataSource {
    func thisWorks() {}
}
```